DynamicModule updating Graphics with scheduled task
I am trying to make animations that move around using DynamicModule and changing the local variables using a scheduled task within the module. However, I can't get the graphics itself to update properly.
Here is an example. My first attempt was something like this:
add [] := DynamicModule[{x = 0}, 
     {Graphics[{Red, Circle[{0, 0}, Dynamic@x]}], 
   Dynamic@x}, 
  Initialization :> (task = CreateScheduledTask[x += 1; 1]; 
    StartScheduledTask[task];)]

But this did not update the graphics nor the text at all. I did some searching and was able to find a workaround for the text: apparently Dynamic@x fails but Dynamic@{x} works. But I still can't get the graphic itself to update. I would greately appreciate it if an explanation is given.

By the way, changing x into a global variable works well. I modified my program by creating a bunch of global variables for now, but am still looking for answers with local variables.

For a workaround you can try to update more than x, a whole Circle primitive here:
add[] := DynamicModule[
  {x = 0},
  {
   Graphics[{Red, Dynamic@Circle[{0, 0}, x]}, PlotRange -> 5],
   Dynamic@{x}
  },
  Initialization :> (
    task = CreateScheduledTask[x += 1; 1, {1, 5}];
    StartScheduledTask[task];
  )
]


Surprising to see that this works.. honestly have no idea how Dynamic works but this should solve the problem for now.

How about using Animate[] ?
Animate[Graphics[{Red, Circle[{0, 0}, x]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}], {x, 0, 10, 1}, 
 AnimationRunning -> False]


Well the thing is, I am eventually trying to create dynamic graphics for a game, where a ball moves around based on user input. So I thought that using Animate[] wouldn't quite work. This is a good answer but I was looking for explanations using ScheduledTask

@Init see. I know very little about ScheduledTask --- I want to see other answers to this question, too.
